# Why doesnt gzip.open() recognize my compressed file?

Tags: gzip, pickle

I have been trying to extract a large set of images that are in a .pkl.gz file. Here is my code for doing so.

```py
import gzip
import pickle
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

for f in os.listdir("W:\Code\Machine Learning\digit-recognition-dnn\data"):
    print(f)

name = 'mnist.pkl.gz'

with gzip.open(name, 'rb') as f:
    train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f)

train_x, train_y = train_set

plt.imshow(train_x[0].reshape((28, 28)), cmap=cm.Greys_r)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the output is like this:

```
getData.py
mnist.pkl.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "w:\Code\Machine Learning\digit-recognition-dnn\data\getData.py", line 12, in <module>
    with gzip.open(name, 'rb') as f:
  File "C:\Users\trexx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\gzip.py", line 58, in open
    binary_file = GzipFile(filename, gz_mode, compresslevel)
  File "C:\Users\trexx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\gzip.py", line 173, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mnist.pkl.gz'
```

My filetree looks like this:

```
data
├─ getData.py
└─ mnist.pkl.gz
```

Any suggestions?

I tried changing `name` to `

```
name = 'mnist.pkl'
```

and

```
name = 'mnist.gz'
```

The result is the same. FileNotFound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying a path instead of just the name.

Replace `mnist.pkl.gz` with something like `"W:\my_dir\mnist.pkl.gz`

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Any idea why the first one didn't work though? In theory it should be recognized.

Comment: Specifying just `name = 'mnist.pkl.gz'` would probably write to your present working directory, but when you try reading it most likely isn't reading from your present working directory. So specifying the absolute path definitely makes sure you're reading and writing at the same location.